# Topology Question (Does my proof make sense?)

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a continuous map $h: S^1 \to X$, where $S^1$ is the circle. In Munkres there is a proof that if the induced homomorphism $h_*$:$\pi(S^1)$ $\to \pi(X)$ is trivial, then $h$ is nullhomotopic.

I believe I have constructed a much simpler proof, but believe it is wrong otherwise it would be shown in Munkres. Does my proof make sense?

If $h_*$ is trivial, then since $S^1$ is a loop in $S^1$, there exists a homotopy between $h(S^1)$ and the constant loop in x. This is because the loop $h(S^1)$ has the homotopy type of a point. Thus h is nullhomotopic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct.  It's essentially the same as the proof in Munkres; he just writes things out a bit more explicitly and has to do a little more work because his definition of "loop in $X$" is a map $I\to X$ that sends the endpoints of $I$ to the same point, rather than just a map $S^1\to X$.

Comment: The proof in Munkres was very long, it even made use of a quotient map.

Comment: Munkres's formulation is a little more complicated because he defines $\pi_1(X)$ in terms of maps $I\to X$, not maps $S^1\to X$.  The quotient map discussion is just to verify that a homotopy $I\times I\to X$ (rel the endpoints) is the same thing as a homotopy $S^1\times I\to X$ (rel the base point of $S^1$).

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification Eric!